# Diff merge : view difference between two folders and ignore file version number

Tags: merge, diff, version

I need some help. I have to view difference between two folders, but I need to ignore the file version number (project version number) which is in the header of the file. Like that:

```
@version Release: $Revision: 9939 $
```

And do you know the best diff merge software for doing that in Mac OSX and the most beautiful. I know diff merge and Kaleidoscope. I love Kaleidoscope but, it cannot make some difference between two folders.

Many thanks before.

Comment: [diff(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man1/diff.1.html).

Answer (score 4):

Try going into **DiffMerge** → **Preferences** → **File Windows** → **Rulesets**.  You can modify the existing ruleset for your file type (or add a new one if no ruleset exists already).

Edit the ruleset you're interested in, and go to **Lines to Omit**.  In there you can add a regex to match that line `@version`.

What I'm having trouble with is getting the folder diff to honor this.  I find that files with no diffs according to my rules still end up in the folder diff as a non-match, but when I open the file diff window it says `Files are identical or equivalent under the current RuleSet.`  Not sure if this is a bug or I still have something configured wrong.  If I go into **Folder Windows** → **Equivalence Mode** and dig into the help there, I think I have all the folder diff properties set correctly to honor my rulesets, but still no luck.

Answer (score -2):

It's a pity you need MacOS. For Win32 there is WinMerge readily configurable via Tools/Filters/Linefilters where you simply enter a regular expression to be ignored.

http://manual.winmerge.org/Filters.html

> For example, you might use line filters to ignore comments or certain type of generated code, like version control system timestamps

WinMerge 3 will be Qt based hence MacOS positive too, but current 2.x is not yet.

Comment: But I'm on MacOSX ... so ... Anything else ?

Comment: StackOverflow is gradually becoming a true mirror of the internet at large. Anonymous crowd, wielding their mighty anonymous downvoting axe, gets a repeated revenge on a 6 years old answer, which was factually correct at the time of writing. I don't care enough to spend time fixing it or making it more politically correct. Despite being Mac guy now myself. It's been 6 years, folks.